# How do I connect to my local Realtime Database emulator in my Flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the Realtime Database and Functions for my Flutter app. I've set up local emulators for both Database and Functions, so I can test Functions locally without the deployment cost. Now I want to connect my Flutter app to these local emulators, but I am having some trouble finding out how to do it.

The FlutterFire docs describes how to do this for Firestore (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#emulator-usage), but not for the Realtime Database. Surely there must be a way to connect to the emulators, even though I am using the Realtime Database?

I have tried the following:

```
String host = Platform.isAndroid ? '10.0.2.2:4000' : 'localhost:4000';
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase(
      app: Firebase.app(),
      databaseURL: host,
    );
```

But that gives me the error:

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Invalid Firebase Database url specified: 10.0.2.2:4000, null)

I am using the firebase_core and firebase_database packages on pub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Firebase documentation for Android, using the Realtime Database emulator requires a call `database.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9000)`. A quick [search of the FlutterFire code](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/search?q=useEmulator) shows no such calls, so it seems that emulator usage isn't implemented in FlutterFire yet.

I also couldn't find an [open issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22plugin%3A+database%22) for it, so you might want to file a feature request.

Comment: I see. I created a [feature request](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/discussions/3668). Hopefully this will be added in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Digging deeper into Firebase Java SDK, I've found that `.useEmulator()` only sets `host` and `port` for creating the `databaseURL` and in short is just a refactoring wrapper.

Code below should work with FlutterFire Realtime Database package:

```
String host = Platform.isAndroid ? 'http://10.0.2.2:9000' : 'http://localhost:9000';
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase(
  app: Firebase.app(),
  databaseURL: host,
);
```

Also, do check your `firebase.json` for the correct port to use. Default should be `9000` for database.

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me. Did it worked for your?

Answer (score 2):

Following code worked for me. Its almost similar to @Florin Stan answer. Just the namespace of the database was missing.

```
String host = Platform.isAndroid ? 'http://10.0.2.2:9000' : 'http://localhost:9000';
dbInstance= FirebaseDatabase(
    databaseURL: '$host?ns=YOUR_DATABASE_NAMESPACE',
);
```

Database namespace can be found in firebase realtime database emulator UI.