# Is it possible to connect a local Functions emulator to a non-local Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Due to problems using a Realtime Database emulator for development in Flutter (*see [How do I connect to my local Realtime Database emulator in my Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64077650/how-do-i-connect-to-my-local-realtime-database-emulator-in-my-flutter-app)*), I am now simply using my non-local Realtime Database for development. However, I am also using Cloud Functions, and I have created a Functions emulator.

I tried the following to connect to it, based on [this StackOverflow-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920014/functions-debugging-in-vs-code/46023412#46023412):

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
functions.config = () => {
  return {
    firebase: {
      databaseURL: "https://mylink.firebaseio.com/",
    },
  };
};
```

But the emulator is not responding to changes in the database.

So, is it even possible to connect my local Functions emulator to my non-local Realtime Database? It's kind of a weird setup, but I don't know how I am going to be able test functions otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to have the local Cloud Functions emulator respond to (or "trigger" on) events in a production database.  You have to deploy your functions in order for them to execute in response to change in the cloud-hosted database.  The local functions emulator only responds to changes in the locally emulated database.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the quick response!